# How to drop timestamps that return zero if there is no data in InfluxDB

Tags: database, influxdb

My InfluxDB query is:

```
select count(quantity) from test group by time(1d)
```

[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIh4y.jpg)

How do we drop zero?

Answer (score 0):

From the [InfluxDB docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill):

`fill()` changes the value reported for time intervals that have no data.

To return no timestamp for intervals with no data, use `fill(none)`:

```
select count(quantity) from test where time > now()-10d group by time(1d) fill(none)
```

Comment: @lalitbhadouria what does it return without the `fill(none)`? You may need to change the `where` condition...

Comment: `fill(none)` should drop those with count == 0... What is the *exact* query you are running now?